# XHR.onreadyStateChange only firing once?

Tags: node.js, xmlhttprequest

I'm new to node and I'm trying to make a simple xhr to a server and print out to the console when it succeeds with this code:

```
// Code slice of test.js
xhr.open('GET', uri, true); 

xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    console.log("Success!");
  } else {
    console.log("Waiting...");
  }
};

xhr.send();
```

However, when I run this with `node test.js`, it only prints out `Waiting...` once and then never ends execution.

I've tested this code slice in a browser so I know this XHR should work but am I using this wrong?

Comment: Why are you using an antiquated xhr interface in node.js?  I'd suggest using the `request()` library.

Comment: In `node-xmlhttprequest`, you will miss some events because you are calling `xhr.open()` before you set your `onreadystatechange` callback.

Comment: @jfriend00 all the tutorials call `.open()` before adding the `onreadystatechange` callback.

Comment: You should always add your event handlers before kicking off the process.  That's a good habit to get in node and I can see in the node-xmlhttprequest code that at least one event will be missed if you call `.open()` before.  And, keep in mind that the node-xmlhttprequest is doing a simulation of something in the browser so event timing could certainly be slightly different if you're looking at browser tutorials.  Really, in node.js, you should be using the `request()` library. It's simpler and better and a more direct way of programming.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm dealing with legacy code and am stuck with XHR's. And `open()` only changes the state, the `onreadystatechange` callback only needs to be set before `send()`

Comment: Which exact library are you using for xhr in node.js?